# Is each multiplicative linear functional on $L^1(SL(2,R):SO(2,R))$ is triviall?

Tags: harmonic-analysis

We know that if $G=SL(2,R)$ and $H=SO(2,R)$ as a compact subgroup of $G$, then $\{\xi \in \hat{G}; \xi|_H=1\}$is triviall. Can we conclude that  each multiplicative linear functional on $\{f\in L^1(G); R_\xi f=f(a.e)\forall \xi \in H\}$ is triviall, too?

Comment: If memory serves right, $L^1(SL(2,R),SO(2,R))$ is a commutative Banach algebra -- this is a Gelfand pair, isn't it? -- and it is moreover semisimple. I don't recall the proof but I think you can write down explicit characters on this algebra using the spherical functions associated to this Gelfand pair.

Comment: Thank you. But it isn't commutative B.al.

Comment: Oh, my mistake: I was thinking of SO(3)-bi-invariant functions. Your question is asking about one-sided SO(3)-invariant functions, right?

Comment: Dear  Yemon Choi, Can  you refer to a good reference in this regard.

Comment: For one-sided invariant functions, I guess the book of Reiterand Stegemann may have something; but it may not deal with the particular case that you are after